# How to summon CMD from a keyboard shorcut

Tags: windows-7, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, cmd.exe

Is there a keyboard shortcut for CMD or the Developer Command Prompt? or a way I can customise my keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7? I find Win + R + "whatever" horribly aggravating.

Comment: does your keyboard support custom programmable keys? thats the easy way. Otherwise you should look into Hotkey pollers like AutoHotKey.

Comment: You can find Windows 7 keyboard reference to see there is nothing. So check the AutoHotKey (www.ahkscript.org) and define keyboard shortcuts as your wish.

Comment: Can't you just assign a shortcut to CMD.EXE? I have Ctrl+Alt+M assigned to CMD.exe on Win10/Win7 and pressing it will run CMD immediately. I did have to add it to the taskbar first but after that the Shortcut-key worked. So open start, press cmd, right click it and "Pin to taskbar". After that rightclick the icon on taskbar and rightclick `Command Prompt` and choose Properties. There you can set the shortcut.

Comment: I found keyboard shortcut lacking, as it makes difficult launching CMD as Administrator. My solution was to pin it to Start Menu and it's as simple as pressing Windows key and then `Arrow down` or, if "Run as Administrator" is needed then either `Left Mouse Click' on on it or equivalent key on keyboard..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windows 7 does not have a CMD keyboard shortcut. If you had some sort of re-programmable software for your keyboard, then you could write a small script (or macro) to run when you press a certain button (e.g. when you press the down arrow, it would run the script and open CMD). If not I suggest you take a look at AutoHotKey and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to write a `.bat` script containing the following :

```
start cmd.exe
```

and launch that script with a macro like all of the "gaming keyboards" have.